# Socket.io and Express with ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket Io in my server and when I try to acessas the service was I create the browser its given this error:

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Here is my server code:

```js
'use strict';

const chalk = require('chalk');
const _ = require('lodash');
const fs = require('fs');

let options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("privkey.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem")
  };
const app = require('express')(options);
const https = require('https').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(https,{origins:'*:*'});
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
const upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data

const sockets = {};

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

https.listen(3002, function () {
    console.log(chalk.yellow("Serviço rodando na porta 3002"));
});
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(chalk.green("Cliente Conectado"));
    sockets[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(chalk.red("Cliente Disconectado"));
        delete  sockets[socket.id];
    });
});


app.post('/atualizador', upload.array(), function (req, res) {
    _.each(sockets,function(socket,idSocket){
        console.log(idSocket);
        socket.emit('posicao',req.body);
    });
    res.send('Atualizador ON');
});
```

And here is the client code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io('https://localhost:3002/');
  socket.on('posicao', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
  });
</script>
```

This certs and privatekey already is used on my domain and why is not working on socket.io and express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass nothing to express and `options` and `app` to [https.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener):

```
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https').Server(options, app);
```

Comment: It worked my friend but now  i'm emitting a messagem from server to client and is it sending but is not arriving on client. Why it happens?